# regular expression match Thursday, Thurs, Thur,Thu

Tags: expression, match, partial

I want a regexp to match partial weekday names.  For example, I want to match "Thursday", "thurs", "thur" or "Thu".  I tried "thu(rsday)?", but that only matched "thu" and "thursday".  The complete regular expression to match abbreviated weekdays would be excessively long.  I tried this regex string:

> Mon(day)?|Tue(sday)?|Wed(nesday)?|Thu(rsday)?|Fri(day)?|Sat(urday)?|Sun(day)?

The strings I have look like this:

> 3-Dec Mon 1:00pm  Premiere    USPHL   Sk3-Red
>
> 4-Dec Tue 8:10pm  U16 USPHL   Sk3-Red
>
> 6-Dec Thur    1:00pm  Premiere    USPHL   Sk3-Red

Comment: What type of regular expression? Does it need to be POSIX, Perl, ECMAScript, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure what those terms are, but I'm running an AutoIT script and calling a function called StringRegexp()  See details here"
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle I'd do this where I want to select where the string matches a weekday.  I suspect you can tweak the regular expression to fit your environment:

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select '3-Dec Mon 1:00pm Premiere USPHL Sk3-Red' from dual union all
  select '4-Dec Tues 8:10pm U16 USPHL Sk3-Red' from dual union all
  select '6-Dec Thursday 1:00pm Premiere USPHL Sk3-Red' from dual
)
select str
from tbl
where regexp_like(str, ' (mon|tue(s)?|wed(nes)?|Thu(r)?(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)? ', 'i');
```

Comment: I really didn't explain myself clearly.  I want to compare the beginnings of each weekday name up to the last character.  So, I want to compare names like this: thu thur thurs followed by 'day'.  I want to do this for each weekday name.  In some parlance, the code would look for: thu[r[s[day]]]  and wed[n[e[s[day]]]] etc.

Comment: That's what this does.  Maybe not to the detail you need but there's enough for you to go on.  The regex looks for mon OR tue (followed by an optional 's' OR wed (followed by an optional 'nes'), etc and all of that followed by an optional 'day'.  To make 'day' required, removed the question mark. The regex pattern should work for you. This matches thu, thur, thurs and thursday for instance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the help.  I ended up with this regexp:

> (?i)((mon|tue(s)?|wed((((n)?e)?s)?)?|thu(r)?(s)?|fri|sat(ur)?|sun)(day)?)

A little more complicated than I wanted, but it works.  I'll need plenty of comments in my code ;-)