# How to cut the rightmost string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to clean up the address data, specifically remove the right most string  as 'road', 'rd', 'street', 'ave' etc (so the number of characters I want to remove is different). I'm using Oracle. Also would like to know how I can do this in Excel as well. Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by right most string ? can you give me example of a word and how you want it to be

Comment: Try to find the last space and then cut till that position. Also, here any question is more welcomed if it comes with some code you tried.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. thanks

Comment: I mean if you have a few words in a cell how to delete the last word (most right). Now I want to delete not only the last word but certain words from a cell such as 'road', 'NE', 'ave' ( I realized I have sometimes in the middle of the cell). What I'm trying to do is to clean up the data so I can match  to another table in excel. I hope this makes sense. Thank you for your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(str, ' [^ ]+$', '')
from (select 'abcd asdf 90909 ddd' as str from dual) x
```

What is handy about `regexp_replace()` is that you can be more explicit about the strings you want to replace:

```
select regexp_replace(str, ' (road|rd|street|ave)$', '')
```

Comment: Thank you!I have this in openquery: regexp_replace(rm.mail_address_1, ''(.||road||rd||drive||dr||avenue||ave||street||st||NE||NW||CT||SW)$'', '' '') but It removes only the last character, not the whole string. Ex. 4520 Hampton Road I want to get 4520 Hampton. Right now what I'm getting is 4520 Hampton Roa.

Comment: One pipe instead of 2. In regular expressions, that's an OR.

Comment: Do it like this: `' (road|rd|dr(ive)?|ave(nue)?|st(reet)?|NE|NW|CT|SW)$'` `dr` by itself or followed by an optional `ive` covers both 'dr' and 'drive'.  See this post for similar matching with days of the week: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641254/2543416